# jQuery removeClass not working on popup

Tags: jquery, popup, removeclass

Here is my code

```
jQuery('.woshadow').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.popup-list').addClass('popup-listh');
    jQuery(this).find('.close-popup').addClass('popup-listh');
});

jQuery('.close-popup').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find('.popup-list').removeClass('popup-listh');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('popup-listh');
});
```

when i use addClass instead of removeClass it's fine and work properly but it is not working with removeClass that is realy rare any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you add your html code ?

Comment: Please add the html code as well. Which version of jquery are you using (maybe it's better to use `on('click', ...)`)?

Comment: I suspect some event propagation... If you click on `.close-popup`, event propagate to `.woshadow` level, and so re-add class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you click on .close-popup, event propagate to .woshadow level, and
>   so re-add class

Simple fix is to stop event propagation on child element:

```
jQuery('.close-popup').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).parent().find('.popup-list').removeClass('popup-listh');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('popup-listh');
});
```